# There is delay from Dropdown selection. It is showing previous selected item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Once I click submit, I don't get reaction until I click another selection. Then I will see the first selection. So I am always seeing the previous selection

```js
function watchForm() {
  $('.drop-form').on('click', function(event) {
    var breed = $('#breed').val()
    getPhoto(breed)
  })
}

function getPhoto(name) {
  console.log(name)
  fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${name}/images/random`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => renderPhoto(responseJson))
}

function renderPhoto(object) {
  $('.picture').html(`
    <h1>Your dog</h1>
    <img src=${object.message} alt="hmmm">`)
}

$(function() {
  console.log(`'js' up and running`)
  watchForm();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for='breed'>Fetch (get it?)</label>
  <select id='breed' class='breed' name='breed'>
    <option value=''>Please Choose</option>
    <option value='affenpinscher'>Affenpinscher</option>
    <option value='african'>African</option>
    <option value='airdale'>Airdale</option>
  </select><br>
  <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: There is no `.drop-form` element in your HTML...

Comment: Well there is an Fetch request that takes time, that http request is not instant. So you need to wipe away the old content, maybe add loading icon.

Comment: @epascarello. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding a click event on the form I would suggest adding a change event on the select element.

In other words, instead of:

```
$('.drop-form').on('click', function(event){
  var  breed = $('#breed').val()
  getPhoto(breed)
})
```

Add an event directly on the select element:

```
$('#breed').change(function(event){
  var  breed = $('#breed').val()
  getPhoto(breed)
})
```